# Merge only certain parts of files

Tags: git, git-merge, gitignore

I'm new to Git (version control in general). I believe there is an easy solution for my problem just that I haven't been able to find it.

I do most of my changes to a local branch say X.

Both the master and X have a config files (master has config of server, local that of my localhost) which are different. So when I merge X into master I have to add config to git ignore. That works, but what should I do when I need to change my configuration on X and the same should apply to master?

Comment: Related [How to maintain an unpopulated 'config' source file in git repo?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/290104/108627) on Programmers SE

Comment: I posted how you can do what you asked for, but you don't really want to be doing that - you should put user- or environment-specific config values in environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no easy solution. In fact, there is no practical solution either.

One of fundamental properties of 3-way merge is that if you merge branch A to B and then (immediately) B to A, you will get the same state on both branches. This is true in all version control systems, but even more obvious in Git, because Git will look at the history, realize there are no changes on B and simply move B to point to the same revision as A. Combined with the fact that Git always¹ merges the whole tree this means that keeping a file different between branches while merging some file both ways would require manually handling that file each and every time and never forgetting. Not practical.

The version control repository with source is not the right place for environment-specific file anyway exactly because the source will be used in environments that each requires different config.

The recommended procedure is to have a versioned template and *unversioned* actual config that is used. See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/290104/108627.

---

¹ Actually, there are some exceptions, like the subtree strategy, but none of them matches this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using SourceTree.